# How to clear form fields after a submit in laravel

Tags: html

```
 <div class="form-group">
          <label>Class</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control text-capitalize" name="user_class" value="{{Input::old('user_class')}}" placeholder="Class">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
            @foreach($errors->get('user_class') as $user_class)
            <div class="alert alert-danger error">{{$user_class}}</div>
            @endforeach
          </div>
        </div>
```